# How to return the sum of even row numbers in R data frame?

Tags: r

I am very new to coding.

I'm looking to retrieve frequency values of rows in my data frame

I already know you can do this using:

```
df$col <- rowSums( data[,0:100] )
```

But I specifically want the sum of data from rows that are divisible by two, in other words, even rows up to a specific point in my data frame.

Perhaps you would need to incorporate an if else function? 
Something vaguely similar to this oversimplified code?

```
   if df$col[0:5]%%2
    print rowSum
   else:
    don't
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Much appreciated

Comment: Probably `rowSums(dat[seq_len(nrow(dat)) %% 2 == 0L,0:100] )`.

Comment: Please read [Ask] and [mcve] ... **then edit your question!**

Comment: `rowSums(cars[c(FALSE, TRUE), ])`

Comment: @jogo  But my question really is simple? I have to put up code for that? I just want to calculate the sum of even row numbers. That is all. I thought it was pretty generic? I have a data frame. I just want to calculate the row of even numbers from that data frame. Shall I show you the data frame and highlight using editing tools the rows divisible by two I want to get the sum of? Would that help?

Comment: "row of even numbers" and "even row numbers" can be seen as two completely different things.  Please be more specific and include a reproducible example with desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
st.mat <- matrix(1:100,ncol = 10, nrow =10)
for(i in 1:dim(st.mat)[1]){
 if(i %% 2 == 0){
  print(sum(st.mat[i,]))
 }
}
```

This would be a very simple way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Indexing with a logical vector and the recycling rule will give the nice solution:

```
rowSums(cars[c(FALSE, TRUE), ])
```